# Regex to wrap email address in mailto from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Want to turn `some text email@address.com` into `some text <a href="mailto:email@address.com">email@address.com</a>`

Below is the regex I'm using in replace:

`'some text email@address.com'.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}' + '\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.' + ')+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)/gi, '<a href='mailto:$1'>$1</a>');`

The regex is not working properly, please help.

Comment: The simplest regex I know for email is: `\S+@\S+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Toto, you can use this regex `\S+@\S+` to include every possible (and non-possible) characters in the email excluding the space.

```
(\S+@\S+)
```

If you want to include only English characters `a-z`, numbers `0-9`, dots `.`, underscores `_`, and dashes `-` . You can do it this way:

```
([\w\.\-]+@\w+\.\w+)
```

If you want to add to the previous one every possible character from any language `à è ì ò ù`, and at the same time, exclude special characters `% ^ & *`, you can use `\pL` as follows:

```
([\w\.\-\pL]+@\w+\.\w+)
```

Demo for the last Regex:

```js
    var Email = "some text email@address.com.";
    Email = Email.replace(/([\w\.\-\pL]+@\w+\.\w+)/g, '<a href=mailto:$1>$1</a>');
    document.write (Email);
```

Comment: great answer! How can we account for a string with period at the end such as "something email@address.com."? The last comma needs to be removed.

Comment: @Steve, Oh yeah, the comma. I forgot about it. I fixed my code. Check the updated answer and the demo. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replacer function](http://'some%20text%20email@address.com'.replace(/%5CS+@%5CS+/gi,%20'%3Ca%20href='mailto:$0'%3E$0%3C/a%3E');) of `replace()` function:

```js
var str = "some text email@address.com";
var regex = /\w+@\w+\.\w+/gi;

var replacedString = str.replace( regex, function(match){
  return '<a href="'+match+'">'+match+'</a>';
});

console.log( replacedString );
```

Comment: What about email like: `Jean-François@localhost`? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples some some valid emails.

Comment: @Toto :) I assumed emails to be of form abc@xyz.pqr. Is that not sufficient practically?

Comment: No, it is not. Some common emails: `firstname.lastname@domain.uk.com`, `abc-def@whatever-you-want`

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I was doing something like this in my code and had to fix a bug where the email address is already wrapped in a mailto link. This was my simple solution to that problem:

```
var rx = /([mailto:\w.\-pL]+@\w+.[\w.\-pL]+)/gi
return str.replace(rx, function (match) {
  return (match.indexOf('mailto') === 0) ? match : `<a href="mailto:${match}">${match}</a>`
})
```

The regex optionally matches "mailto:" and the replacer function checks to see if it is in the match, and returns it unmodified if so.

Maybe this will help a fellow google-passer-by.